# Receive error when trying to post a user to sqlite database with postman

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, knex.js

I get this error when trying to post a user to my users database. I have done projects like these before but never got this error.

"errno": 14,
    "code": "SQLITE_CANTOPEN"

I have looked this issue up but most don't have solutions or are not using knex.
Edit: added knexfile.js.

```js
//-----------my routes file---------
// imports
const axios = require("axios");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const db = require("../../../data/dbConfig");

// import middlewares from file
const { generateToken, protected } = require("../../middlewares/middlewares");

// exports
module.exports = server => {
  server.post("/api/post/usertodb", createUser);
  server.get("/api/get/userfromdb"), getUser;
};

function createUser(req, res) {
  const newUser = req.body;
  console.log(db);
  db("users")
    .insert(newUser)
    .then(ids => res.status(201).json(ids[0]))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).json(err));
}

//--------my dbConfig file is-----------
const knex = require("knex");
const knexConfig = require("../knexfile");

module.exports = knex(knexConfig.development);



//--------my server.js file-------------
// imports
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

// configure routes
const configureRoutes = require("../config/routes/users/userRoutes");

// instantiate server
const server = express();
server.use(express.json());
server.use(cors());
configureRoutes(server);

// export server
module.exports = {
  server
};

//----------knexfile.js---------
    module.exports = {
      development: {
        client: "sqlite3",
        connection: {
          filename: "./data/filmsydb.sqlite3"
        },
        useNullAsDefault: true,
        migrations: {
          directory: "./data/migrations"
        },
        seeds: {
          directory: "./data/seeds"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What's in `knexfile`? Also, make sure that the DB file exists and is readable

Comment: The DB exists and can be opened with my sqlite DB browser. I'll add in the knexfile.

Answer (score 0):

It was a permissions issue. I just moved folder from out of folder it was in and it worked.